# Why do the Sound Settings ignore the Output Device?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 20.04, headset

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenove Thinkpad T470. I have a Bose QC25 headset connected via Bluetooth using only the output with A2DP because the HSP/HFP profile is implemented so poorly.

Currently the headset is successfully connected, I can select the headset in the sound settings, I can switch to A2DP just fine ... and the sound i still played through the internal speakers. Since the whole setup worked just fine until now I was assuming a reboot would fix this but that is not the case.

A short term solution is to install `pavucontrol` and switch the port of the build-in audio to from `Speaker` to `Headphone`. This is wrong because that should only be the case if the headphones were connected to the audio jack - but by "destroying" the internal audio this way the sound is now played through the selected device (the BT headphones).

This is by no means a fix since the problem returns after rebooting or suspending. Any idea how to fix this for good?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I still have no idea what exactly went wrong but the fix for me was simple. It might have to do with Skype, though.

> For some reason, pulseaudio's user configuration files can become corrupt(unsynced?) in some way, and deleting them (and forcing fresh ones to be generated) fixes a no sound condition. After using the command below, log out/in.

```bsh
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#Resetting_User_Configuration

For me this fixed everything without even having to log out and in. Just had to reconnect the headphones and things work again.

Comment: This is apparently a known issue with pulseaudio (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1866194) and the fix to delete the `.config/pulse` folder is recommended there also. A patch will be released with Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Despite that bug being listed as fixed, I just experienced this issue in Ubuntu 22.04 and the fix in this answer worked for me.