# headset combo microphone works earphones don't work

Tags: sound, alsa, realtek, audio-jack

I have a self-built desktop using MSI MPGZ390 motherboard with onboard sound chip Realtek ALC1220P Codec. The headset is Hyperx Cloud Core with 2 3.5mm jacks plugged into front of computer. It is a dual-boot system and the headset works fine on Windows 10.
On Ubuntu the earphones work fine on Firefox/YouTube. Audio CDs are also good.
On Settings/Sound/Output Device when clicking on "Test" there is no sound. Speaking into microphone shows a signal under Input Device.

Comment: so only the 'test' buttons aren't playing sound?  make sure the output profile is set right.  You can also run `pavucontrol` and it will tell you what device it's trying to play the test sound out of.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. pavucontrol/outputdevices shows the same as settings/sound/outputdevices "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo". I tried to upload images of pavucontrol etc. but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the USB version of the HyperX headset.
I first tried upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 but then the output would always go to my other headset regardless of what I selected as output in the settings.

Removing pulseaudio settings and restarting it solved it for me:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

Solution found in this thread:
[Why do the Sound Settings ignore the Output Device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250225/why-do-the-sound-settings-ignore-the-output-device/1250597#1250597?newreg=02d7c434a55e474da89bc03473e73e27)
I suspect that the original issue may have been corrupt pulseaudio settings too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1255738)

Comment: Good point. Updated.